# Mobile Layout Screenshot Service

Tags: testing, mobile, screenshot

Is there a service like Browsercam.com that tests mobile browsers aswell?

I've only found sites like DeviceAnywhere.com, but those test the whole platform, not only the browser

it should at least support Android and iOS, in different resolutions and landscape/portrait mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of cource, few minutes after the opening of the thread, I find the perfect service.
The only one I could find with mobile testing

http://crossbrowsertesting.com